# Add column to data frame to match geographic coordinates with location name

Tags: r, coordinates, matching

I have a data frame (df1) containing millions of rows of bike ride data for a bike share company. There are 17 columns, but I'm only interested in all data under four columns.

1. loc_id
2. ride_type
3. lat
4. lng

Each location ID on df1 has a matching latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) shown in its own respective column. So, every time an observation repeats under the loc_id column, the matching observations under lat and lng repeat.

When I run the following script, lat and lng don't appear in the new, smaller data frame (df2) that results.

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  count(loc_id, ride_type)
```

Here are the first six rows of output:

```
            loc_id      ride_type    n
1            13001        casual   14109
2            13001        member   11769
3            13006        casual    3459
4            13006        member    7164
5            13008        casual   33316
6            13008        member    8971
```

I want the output to follow the pattern below, though. How can I do it?

```
            loc_id      ride_type   n        lat         lng
1            13001        casual   14109   41.88398   -87.62468
2            13001        member   11769   41.88398   -87.62468
3            13006        casual    3459   41.77937   -87.66484
4            13006        member    7164   41.77937   -87.66484
5            13008        casual   33316   41.80594   -87.59247
6            13008        member    8971   41.80594   -87.59247
```

df2 is meant to summarize df1 so that each loc_id appears only twice: once to show the number of casual rides that started there and again to show the number of member rides that started there.

I ran the following:

```
df2 %>%
  left_join(select(df1, c(loc_id, lat, lng)), by = c("loc_id" = "loc_id"))
```

This didn't work for me because it added to df2 all rows from df1. The following output is the first 10 rows of df2 that resulted from the join.

```
              loc_id   member_casual    n       lat     lng
1              13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
2              13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
3              13001        casual    14109  41.88381 -87.62401
4              13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
5              13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
6              13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
7              13001        casual    14109  41.88377 -87.62445
8              13001        casual    14109  41.88403 -87.62416
9              13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
10             13001        casual    14109  41.88398 -87.62468
```

That's not what I'm going for. Instead of a join, should I try whatever R uses as an equivalent to Excel's VLOOKUP? Either way, what's the simplest way to do this? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include column selection within your join command to merge the two data frames together.

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(select(df1, c(loc_id, lat, lng), by = c("loc_id" = "loc_id"))
```

You don't technically need the `by` portion of the join statement since both data frames have the same column name, but it's more explicit as to what you're joining.

**Edit** ---------------------

From the snippet of results you provided it looks like each loc_id has multiple, unique latitude and longitude values, which is why so many rows are being joined.

If the latitude and longitude values for each loc_id are all roughly similar and aren't informative, then you could use the `distinct()` function to keep the first two rows of each grouping.

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(select(df1, c(loc_id, lat, lng), by = c("loc_id" = "loc_id")) %>% 
  distinct(loc_id, lat, lng, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Or if you don't need a lot of precision around the lat and long for each loc_id, you could use the `round()` function to reduce the number of decimals each lat and long has within your df1 data frame prior to merging. This would reduce the number of unique values that would be joined.

In the alternative, and I'm sure that might also raise other issues, but if your points are all very close together, you could try taking the average of the lat and long for each loc_id.

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(select(df1, c(loc_id, lat, lng), by = c("loc_id" = "loc_id")) %>% 
  group_by(loc_id, member_casual, n) %>% 
  summarise(lat = mean(lat), lng = mean(lng))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! That DID add the lat and lng.

However, this didn't work for me because it added to df2 all rows from df1. 

I'm trying to keep df2 as a summary of df1 that shows each loc_id only twice: once to show the number of casual riders that used a location and once to show the number of member riders that used that same location.

Do you think there might be a way to rearrange this join so that it accomplishes that? Alternatively, should I try whatever R's version of Excel's VLOOKUP is?

Comment: I hadn't noticed about the multiple slightly distinct latitudes and longitudes per loc_id until you pointed it out. Thank you for that and for your suggestions! The distinct function was giving me a sort of quirky result for some reason, but that last alternative with the summarise function is the one that worked very well. Thanks again!